# How to open a clam antivirus database file

Tags: clamav

I want to read the contents of a .CVD file (Clam AV database file).

How can I do this?  I tried deleting the first 512 bytes of the file and then rename it to `.tar.gz` but it won't open.

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Clam AV has libraries that you can use to read at least some of the data from the CVD files.

Comment: i want to create an antivirus.so i need the database to open and read the signatures

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best way to strip the header:

```
dd if=clam.cvd of=clam.tar.gz bs=512 skip=1
```

Then you can use tar to extract:

```
tar xzvf clam.tar.gz
```

Comment: sorry but i didn't realize this codes...where can i write this codes?is it Linux codes?

Comment: @PouyanIzadi yes, this is linux.  Just do this from a bash shell to extract the files.

Answer (score 1):

ClamAV comes with a tool to verify and also extract database files called **sigtool**.  To extract you can run

```
sigtool -u clam.cvd
```

which will extract the files in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little golang package that downloads and extracts parts of the clamwin mdb files.

https://github.com/codeallthethingz/clamwin-downloader